# How to Integrate Apache Kafka Connect with Azure Schema Registry?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, azure-eventhub

I have tried to use confluent avro converter to connect with Azure schema registry(providing schema registry url and value converter to avroConverter) but couldn't connect.

Then i came across below repo which was developed for Kafka client applications. But how can i use it with Kafka connect?

Github Repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-schema-registry-for-kafka

i could see in the codebase they are forming TokenCredential object and sending it along with schema registry url to KafkaAvroSerializer. How can we do this in Kafka connect as Kafka producer is baked into it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That repo is only available for Kafka Producer/Consumer API.

You'd need to create your own [`Converter`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/storage/Converter.html) implementation that wraps the Serializer and Deserializer classes available there (then submit a PR, or create an issue asking for a `connect` module be added there).

**Update** - There is now a Converter in that repo.